# How to make jsDoc "import" work with vscode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, mobx-state-tree

I want to import a node module with @import, but it seems visual studio code is not getting it. Or am I doing it wrong?

[image: Missing type in visual studio code]

Comment: I believe `@import` is a function in TypeScript, not JSDocs for JS.

Comment: AFAIK jsDoc is using TypeScript internally

Comment: JSDocs predates TypeScript by at least 5 years. Maybe 10. As I understand it, TypeScript uses Closure Compiler, which uses JSDocs, but it’s built upon what closure could do, such as adding an `import` directive.

Comment: It's actually stupid what I wrote above. I meant: AFAIK vscode is using TypeScript internally to make sense of jsDoc directives.

Comment: The question doesn't mention TypeScript. If you are using TS, you should add the TypeScript tag to your question. FWIW: You might want to read up on it's language server https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API Even if it doesn't help, it is fascinating :D

Answer (score 11):

Personally I would suggest TypeScript over JSDoc.

Nevertheless, try something like this? (there is no `@import` tag in JSDoc).

```js
// path/to/UiStore.js

/**
 * @typedef UiStore
 * @type {object}
 * @property {string} foo - description for foo
 * @property {string} bar - description for bar
 */
```

```js
// path/to/another.js

/** @typedef {import("path/to/UiStore").UiStore} UiStore */

/** @type {UiStore} */
const uiStore = {
  foo: 'hello',
  bar: 'world',
};
```

With mobx-state-tree it works like this:

In file UiStore.js:

```
export const UiStoreType = UiStore.Type
```

and then in path/to/another.js

```
/**
 * @typedef Props
 * @prop { import("../stores/UiStore").UiStoreType } uiStore
 * @prop { import("../stores/DbStore").DbStoreType } dbStore
 */
```

Comment: This works within VSCode (assuming your eslint settings are set to TypeScript), but doesn't work with the generated docs.

Comment: _(Diverges a little from the dir structure of your code, but..)_ is there any way to avoid rewriting the `import` directive for each StoreType that one wants to import? Something like: `@typedef {import("../stores/StoresMap")} Stores` and then simply use `@prop { Stores.UiStoreType } uiStore` & `@prop { Stores.DbStoreType } dbStore`?